# Org Mode - Stop Recurring Events From Appearing as Late on Agenda

Tags: org-mode

I am using the org mode agenda and my issue is that recurrent scheduled items appear as late everyday.

For example an event that happens every Tuesday will also appear every Wednesday as 1 day late, on Friday as 2 days late etc...

There is no reason why I would want that, so how can I stop those "late" events from appearing, except on the dates they are scheduled to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a plain timestamp rather than a scheduled or deadline timestamp.

Comment: Nice, simple solution. Great! Thank you.